# Growing Partition Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning

At 1st, I had a Windows machine.  I thought Ubuntu sounded neat to dual boot with, and so it was.  Now I want to put more than 60 GB towards Ubuntu.  More like 200 GB.  Is there any way I can do that now that I have system data and all on there already?  In Windows I have lots of free space to put more towards Ubuntu. (Like 300 GB)

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step process - 1st, reduce the size of the windows partition, 2nd increase the size of your Ubuntu partition.  You will need a live USB or CD to complete the process.

1st:  Reduce the windows partition

Start windows - inside windows, find the disk manager - depending upon the version of windows it will be in different places.  Use Windows disk manager to shrink the size of the windows partition.

**Do not** use Ubuntu tools to change your windows partition - doing so may make your Windows OS unusable

After windows finishes shrinking the partition, you can start the second bit.

2nd:  Boot from the Live CD / USB- choose the 'Try Ubuntu' option.

Open a terminal window <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Enter the command

`sudo apt-get install gparted`

Then enter the command `gparted`

You *can* use gparted to increase the size of the Ubuntu partition to include the extra space left by Windows, assuming it is contiguous to the Ubuntu partition.

**Please, please, please**

Take the time to perform a backup before you do this!

Comment: +1 if I could for the backup point (I've run out today)! Very important!

Comment: Don't use GParted to shrink the Windows partition! I am warning you! I had a Windows 8 installation with a 460 GB partition. I used Disk Management (a partitioner that comes with Windows) to shrink it, and Windows wouldn't let me shrink it any more than 200 GB or so even though I had 150 GB of files. Windows needs that space for files that can't be moved, and GParted isn't smart enough to know how Windows partitions work. If I had used GParted, I wouldn't have Windows right now. Use DIsk Management!

Comment: Backups are always important before any system change. And reboot Windows immediately after the resize to let it run chkdsk and remove the chkdsk needed flag. Otherwise gparted may not see partition correctly.

Comment: There is no need to install gparted on a live DVD/USB. It is already installed, even though when you install it gparted is not installed by default.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste  Sometimes Windows will allow more shrinkage if you run the resize operation multiple times. Required reboot between attempts...